# History: Prevalence of Torah study

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, torah-study, geography

Historically, when has *Torah* study throughout the world been most prevalent, and when has *Torah* suffered relatively limited study and knowledge thereof? Are there any sources that break this down?

It may have to be broken down by place as well (e.g. at one point, Spain may have had very widespread knowledge of *Torah*, while France had very minimal knowledge).

Comment: Dear close-voter: This question is 100% on-topic, as it is about the history of *Judaism*. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1499/2

Comment: I think that there are more people in Yeshiva now than at any other time. Consider how many are in the Mir Yeshivah in Yerushalaim alone. Also see what the Art Scroll revolution has brought as far as Torah publishing.

Comment: @sabbahillel I agree. Also, I'm not sure if it's indicative of minimal Torah study per se, but in his introduction to Mishneh Torah, Rambam writes that "the wisdom of our sages has disappeared, and the understanding of our discerning men are hidden," which is why he wrote Mishneh Torah. But I'm still looking for a more comprehensive list of when the "golden ages" were and when the "dark ages" were.